# How to add custom scripts bundle in NextJS

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, bundle

I have some legacy custom javascripts that I need to bundle and put them in `_document.js` as a link. The filename should include a hash.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I tried webpack configs regarding entry/output but they break NextJs build.

The problem is that we use things like window, document, etc that do crash in server side.

Ideally what is needed is to inject this into a  tag, as compiled / babelified javascript code.

What I tried is

- Webpack HTML Plugin plus other plugins like InlineChunk or
  InlineSource plugins. They didn't work because they generate code in
  an index.html that is not used by NextJS.
- Using Raw Loader to get the file content. Doesn't work because it is
  not babelified.
- Adding a custom entry to the Webpack config, like scripts:
  'path/to/my-entry.js'. Didn't work because it adds a hash name to the
  file and I have no way of knowing it.
- Adding a custom entry into the NextJs polyfills. I thought it made
  sense, but the polyfill tag has a nomodule which prevents its code to
  run on new browsers.
- Another options is to add the javascript code as a string, and then using `__dangerouslySetInnerHtml` but the problem is that I lose linter and babel abilities there.
- I tried adding it as a page, but crashes for local development and even on build

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = (nextConfig = {}) =>
  Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
    webpack(config, options) {
      const nextJsEntries = config.entry;
      config.entry = async () => {
        const entries = await nextJsEntries();
        entries['pages/rscripts'] = 'test/test.js';
        return entries;
      };
   ...
```

Then in `_document.js`

```
<script src={`${publicRuntimeConfig.ASSET_PREFIX}/_next/${this.props.buildManifest.pages['/rscripts'][2]}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just import js file like `import 'path/to/js_file'` in your _app.js/app.tsx file

```js
import "../styles/globals.css"
import "../js/test"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

This one works fine for me

Comment: How do you do when you have things like window, alert, etc that are not available in server side?

Comment: i put my js files in `_app.js`/`_app.tsx` file like as i said
Here is my js file: https://hastepaste.xyz/tr/1et1q4e3t41
And it works

Comment: In `pages/mypage.tsx` I do `if (typeof window !== "undefined") { import("path/to/file.js"); }` just under the other `import` statements and it will magically put `path/to/file.js` inside one of the bundles served to the front-end and load it in the browser. It won't load it server-side thanks to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another answer here as I came across this and I believe some things have changed in Next JS. Next now has this [script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) component that you can use to load external scripts or dangerously set a script.

> The Next.js Script component, next/script, is an extension of the HTML
>
> element. It enables developers to set the loading priority of
> third-party scripts anywhere in their application, outside next/head,
> saving developer time while improving loading performance.

The cool thing is you can put them into whatever pages you want, maybe you have a script you want on a homepage, but not other pages, and Next will extract them and place them on the page based on the strategy you select. There are a few gotchas, can't load in the head, `beforeInteractive` is a little finicky, so I would read the link above and the actual [API reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) before making any choices.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script';

function thirdPartyScript() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // just for fun. This actually fires
    // before the onLoad callback
  }, []);
  return (
    <Script
      id="test-script"
      strategy="afterInteractive"
      src="/public/pages/scripts/test.js"
      onLoad={() => {
        console.log('Onload fires as you would expect');
      }}
    />
  );
}
```